# Quotient of the polynomial ring(inclusion relationship)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm not sure this statement is correct or not But I'm guess this statement is false.

**statement)**

Let the ring $R$ and its ideal $I$ and $J$ s.t. $I\subset J$

Then there is a subring(or ideal)  $R_J(\simeq R/J)$  of  the   $R/I$  .

---

So Let me think about the polynomial quotient's ring $F[x]$ for a filed $F$

If we follow the same logical process,

For  $f,g\in F[x]$  $s.t$ $f|g$(ie.$\langle g \rangle  \subset \langle f \rangle$ )

There is a subring $F_f\simeq (F[x] / \langle f \rangle) $ whichi is a ideal of $F[x] / \langle g\rangle$

This would be also false statement.

But it looks like a definetly  ture that

there is a ideal of $Q[x] / \langle (x-1)(x-2) \rangle$ who is a ismorphic with the    $Q[x] / \langle x-1 \rangle$

This is contradict what I've known that the statement is false.

I'm really confused.

The question is

**First)**

Please clarify which one is correct among the statement, the case of the $F[x]$ and its example $Q[x]$.

Plus It would be thankful What I've missed.

**Second)** If the above statement is true,

Can we say that is correct when considering the commutative ring with unity?

(More generalized version)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. The ring $R_J$ has no natural map to $R_I$. Does the question asks whether there exists a subring of $R/I$ that is isomorphic to $R/J$?

Comment: Yes. You catch what I  meant.

Comment: The fact that there is an ideal of $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle(x-1)(x-2)\rangle$ that is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle$ does not contradict the statement. The statement claims that this is true for *all* ideals of *all* rings. You have just found *one* ideal of *one* ring.

Comment: Hmm I just edited my question.

Comment: For your first question: The statement is true if rings are not assumed to be unital and the ring is a module over a field, so it is true for $F[x]$ if $F$ is a field. Your second question is unclear to me.

Comment: But what about the $J=<2>$ and $I = <4>$ for the ring, $R$ is a integer $Z$? Clearly$ I$is a subset of the$ J$, But $ Z_2$ who is a isomorphic with $R/J$ is not a subset of the $R/I$. So Does it only true for the case you stated like a polynomial ring $F[x]$? ($F$ is a field)

Comment: @Servaes, Could you please post the proof of the statement?

Comment: None of your questions make sense semantically; what do you mean by *"...for the ring, $R$ is a integer $Z$?"*? The statement is also true when $R=\Bbb{Z}$, and $\Bbb{Z}/\langle4\rangle$ contains an ideal isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/\langle2\rangle$ as non-unital rings.

Comment: Aha! Considering the $I \subset J $for the ring $R$, Though the $R/J$ is not subset(subring or ideal) of the $R/I$ but thinking about the isomorphism, the statement always true. Is this right Mr. @Servaes?

Comment: Plus The part you pointed, I've mistaken regarding the ismorphic as a same set not a same structure.